# How do I subtract two Object Lists based on the attributes?

Tags: java, list, dictionary, object, java-stream

I have two Java Object Lists

Let's say dataToBeAdded, dataToBeSubtracted

The objects are of the same data type and have multiple attributes

DummyObject{
attr1,
attr2,
attr3,
attr4
}

I want to merge these lists, but in a conditional manner
If attr1, attr2, attr3 are matching in the lists

Subtract the attr4 and make it the part of the list.

If the attributes are not matching

- the element is from list1(dataToBeadded) add it to output as it is
- the element is from list2(dataToBeSubtracted) make attr4 negative (multiply by -1)

This is something like a Full Outer Join kind of operation

I did something using Maps and Streams

```
        Map<String, DummyObj> dataToBeAddedMap = dataToBeAdded.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(obj -> obj.attr1() + obj.attr2() + obj.attr3(), item -> item));

        Map<String, CumulativeSalesDataByHour> dataToBeSubtractedMap = dataToBeSubtracted.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap( obj -> obj.attr1() + obj.attr2() + obj.attr3(), item ->
                        new DummyObject(item.attr1(), item.attr2(), item.attr3(), -1 * item.attr4())));

        Map<String, DummyObject> resultantData = Stream.of(dataToBeAddedMap, dataToBeSubtractedMap)
                .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        Map.Entry::getKey,
                        Map.Entry::getValue,
                        (v1, v2) -> new DummyObject(v1.attr1(),
                                v1.attr2(),
                                v1.attr3(),
                                v1.attr4() + v2.attr4())
                ));

        System.out.println(resultantData.values());
```

This gives me my desired result, but is there any more efficient way to achieve this?

Edit 1:

Adding Input and expected Output

```
        DummyObject a1 = new DummyObject("uuid1", "abcd", "mer1", 20D);
        DummyObject a2 = new DummyObject("uuid1", "pqrs", "mer1", 25D);
        DummyObject a3 = new DummyObject("uuid2", "xyz", "mer1", 18D);

        List<DummyObject> dataToBeAdded = ImmutableList.of(a1,a2,a3);

        DummyObject d1 = new DummyObject("uuid1", "abcd", "mer1", 5D);
        DummyObject d2 = new DummyObject("uuid1", "pqrs", "mer1", 2D);
        DummyObject d3 = new DummyObject("uuid3", "xyz", "mer2", 10D);

        List<DummyObject> dataToBeSubtracted = ImmutableList.of(d1,d2,d3);

        Desired Output
        [

            DummyObject("uuid1", "abcd", "mer1", 15D); // 20-5
            DummyObject("uuid1", "pqrs", "mer1", 23D); // 25-2
            DummyObject("uuid2", "xyz", "mer1", 18D); 
            DummyObject("uuid3", "xyz", "mer1", -10D); 

        ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating two extra `Map` for the elements to add and the elements to subtract, you could immediately create a chained stream with the two `List` and map each element of the subtracting `List` to an element whose `attr4` field is already negated.

Then, you could collect all the objects within a single `Map` with the `collect(Collectors.toMap())` terminal operation. The key would be the concatenation of the first 3 fields, the value would be the object itself while the colliding cases could be handled by creating a new `DummyObj` with the same 3 fields you're grouping by and the fourth field given by the sum of `attr4` of the first and second colliding value (similarly as you were doing in your last stream).

Another small improvement could be not chaining strings with the `+` operator, which creates a new `String` for each concatenation, but instead
using the `String.format()` method which produces a single `String` to group the elements by (less overhead).

```
Map<String, DummyObj> mapRes = Stream.concat(dataToBeAdded.stream(), dataToBeSubtracted.stream().map(obj -> {
            obj.setAttr4(-1 * obj.getAttr4());
            return obj;
        }))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(obj -> String.format("%s%s%s", obj.getAttr1(), obj.getAttr2(), obj.getAttr3()),
                Function.identity(),
                (obj1, obj2) -> new DummyObj(obj1.getAttr1(), obj1.getAttr2(), obj1.getAttr3(), obj1.getAttr4() + obj2.getAttr4())
        ));
```

Here is a link to test the code above:

https://ideone.com/K5qfsI

Comment: Thanks for the solution, just a quick doubt while creating the map, is it okay if I don't create String ? I directly appending the attributes as there data type is string only

Also Intellij suggested me instead of using map to make list2's attr4 negative use peek function, does it have any downsides which I should be aware of

Comment: Do you mean if it is ok to chain the strings with the + operator as you were doing? Yeah, it is ok. It just creates slightly more overhead than generating a single string with format, but it is something noticeable only for large lists of records.

Answer (score 2):

If you truly want performance, you need to rewrite the pipeline - whatever happens that gets you two this question? Make it so that instead you have 2 Maps, using the first 3 attributes as key (perhaps make a new class that represents those 3 on their own).

But, if the pipeline cannot change, the fastest algorithm is:

1. Write a Comparator that sorts these lists.
2. Make 2 iterators (one for each).
3. Make an output list.
4. Loop, making a 'current item' pointer for both iterators.
5. If current-1 is below current-2 (or current-2 is done), copy current-1 and advance iterator-1.
6. If current-2 is below current-1 (or current-1 is done), flip the sign on c-2, add that, and advance iterator-2.
7. If current-1 and current-2 are identical, update attr4 appropriately, then advance both.
8. If both are done, return the output list.

It'd be significantly more code, but it makes no new transient objects whatsoever, except 2 iterators and a comparator.